# Thread run on timer only fires once on app startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a method to run once a minute on the server hosting my web app. In `Global.asax.cs` `Application_Start()`, I have the following code:

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
    e => DatMethod(),
    null,
    TimeSpan.Zero,
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
);
```

Currently I just have `DatMethod` write to a text file with a timestamp. I can see it write once when I hit `F5` and start debugging, but it never runs again.

Is this the right place to be putting the code? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, how can I set this up properly?

Comment: I think this could solve your problem, you are on right way. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Comment: @NikolaMitev Thanks for that reference, I'll try that now.

Comment: @NikolaMitev That worked brilliantly. Thanks mate. If you wanted to post that code as an answer and mention that as your reference, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @NikolaMitev, This approach is wrong, ASP.NET can not keep track of how many work items registered through your approach. And you'll not be notified about application shutdown being started. So you can not stop your work, and no one waits for you to stop your work. You may be also interested in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @tnw So what's Global.asax anyway ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use 10 seconds interval instead of one minute, then you can see that your code will be executed several times, but your code will not continue its execution forever, because garbage collector will collect your timer instance after a while, and in finalizer method of Timer class, it stops all its activities.
If you use static variable for your timer class, then there won't be any problem
But wait, this approach has several problems with ASP.NET threading mechanisms.
Instead you've to use something like http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/
You may be also interested in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx
Let me know if any other information is required.